# Body code from DFP is appearing twice on website

Tags: static-block, coding

I am new to Magento and trying to implement the DFP code on site. I was able to serve one ad out of three without any issue. But the other two are not serving.

There are two parts head and body. Head tag is implemented correctly.

In CMS under static blocks, I add body part. I added it once but it is appearing twice on site.

Any help, will be appreciated!

Comment: Can someone please help me with this. I can share the site URL, there is no issues in DoubleClick tag. I can confirm that in test page it works perfectly fine. I believe its issue with CMS.

Comment: In simple words, trying to serve ads on site through ad server. On pasting jscript tag in CMS static blocks. Tag appears twice on site which is causing issue in serving the ad.
Ready to pay for getting this issue resolved.